# How to install ros-electric-object-recognition?

Tags: ros, object-recognition

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use ROS electric.

I followed [Object Recognition Kitchen](http://ecto.willowgarage.com/recognition/).

This doc says 'Install the ros-electric-object-recognition package from the official ROS repositories.'

I try to install:

```
  sam@/home/sam$ sudo apt-get install ros-electric-object-recognition
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree       
  Reading state information... Done
  E: Unable to locate package ros-electric-object-recognition
  
  sam@/home/sam$
```

How to fix it?

Thank you~

=============================================

ROS apt:

```
  sam@/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ cat ros-latest.list
  # deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu natty main # 停用升級至 natty
  
  sam@/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ cat ros-latest.list.distUpgrade 
  deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu maverick main
  
  sam@/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ cat ros-latest.list.save 
  deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu maverick main
  
  sam@/etc/apt/sources.list.d$
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43845/how-to-install-ros-electric-object-recognition?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-09-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For me, the package exists in electric. I can also see it at packages.ros.org.

Maybe you need to run `sudo apt-get update` first?
Otherwise, what is your apt entry for ROS?

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-09-14**:
I try to use apt-get update but doesn't work. I have updated my original post. What to do next? Thank you~

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-09-14**:
The ros repository in ros-latest.list is commented out. This obviously won't work, just remove the #, run apt-get update again and it should work.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-09-14**:
Note: This automatically happened during the maverick -> natty update. You should have gotten a warning about that from ubuntu and it will probably happen on every ubuntu update again.